# Box in box - fix space between bottom border and bottom border of inner box -

Tags: css, wordpress, height

How can I fix the space between my inner box and the outer box to 15 px, no matter how many lines of text are above the inner box? I attached a sketch too, how it should look like at the end.

There is an outer box with text in it and a second box with text in it too. The space between the two boxes should be always 15 px at the bottom.

```
.BoxBack
background-color: #000;
border: solid 0.5px #000;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 200px;
bottom: -20px;
word-wrap: break-word;


.BoxOut 
background-image:URL("");
background-size: cover;
border: solid 1px gray;
height: 220px;
width: 275px;
```

Comment: "I attached a sketch too" - Where?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: SKETCH -> https://ibb.co/hRYGfT

Comment: Is `.BoxBack` the child of `.BoxOut`? If so, where's the `position: relative`. As currently the element is relative to page and not in place

Comment: Yes, .BoxBack is the child of .BoxOut. I work with Wordpress and that was the code out of my custom css.